Special case of 2-dim subset sum problem with only 0 and 1s
I am currently researching about a statistical project, where a special computer science problem showed up. I am wondering about the following:
Suppose I have many two dimensional vectors all of the form $v_k=(v_{1k},v_{2k})$ with $v_{1k}$ and $v_{2k} \in ${0,1}. And the problem is to decide whether there exist a subset of this vector set, such that:
$\sum{v_{1k}}=L_1$ and $\sum{v_{2k}}=L_2$ for some given constants $L_1,L_2$ holds.

Since I am mathematician and not really deep into that topic, I want to ask, where to classify this problem in terms of computational hardness (I only had one short course there). Given the similarity to the SUBSET SUM Problem, I assume it to be a NP-Problem, nevertheless I could not come up with some clear explanation why.

The problem is nearly trivial, because there are only four possible vectors: $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$.  In particular, it can be solved in polynomial time.
The $(0,0)$ vectors don't matter, since they don't contribute to the sum.  So let $n_{0,1}$ denote the number of $(0,1)$ vectors in your collection, $n_{1,0}$ the number of $(1,0)$ vectors, and $n_{1,1}$ the number of $(1,1)$ vectors.  We are given $n_{0,1},n_{1,0},n_{1,1}$.  The goal is to find integers $x,y,z$ such that
$$x \cdot (0,1) + y \cdot (1,0) + z \cdot (1,1) = (L_1,L_2),$$
i.e., such that
$$y+z = L_1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad x+z = L_2,$$
subject to the constraints $0 \le x \le n_{0,1}$, $0 \le y \le n_{1,0}$, $0 \le z \le n_{1,1}$.
This is a system of linear inequalities in three unknowns, and thus can be easily solved.  Specifically, let
$$\begin{align*}
z &= \min(L_1,L_2,n_{1,1})\\
x &= L_1-z\\
y &= L_2-z.
\end{align*}$$
If this choice of $x,y,z$ satisfies $x \le n_{0,1}$ and $y_{1,0}$, then it is a solution to your problem.  Otherwise, there is no solution to your problem.
